# Не проходит unit test при делении в столбик

Tags: java

Тест программы, которая делает деление в столбик : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс, который выводит результат деления 0 на 100 :

```
     private String drawResultForDividentThatEqualsZero(StringBuilder result, Integer divisor) {
result.append("_0").append(SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR).append(divisor.toString()).append("\n");
result.append(" 0").append(SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR).append("-").append("\n");
result.append(" -").append(SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR).append("0").append("\n");
result.append(" 0");

return result.toString();
```

}

И 2 важных момента :

```
public static final String SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR = "|";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
```

Тест, который не проходит :

```
@Test
public void Should_MakeDivision_When_DividentEqualsZero() {

String expected = "_0│100\n" +
        " 0│-\n" +
        " -│0\n" +
        " 0";
assertEquals(expected, numbersDivision.makeDivision(0, 100));
```

}

Основной метод makeDivison :

```
public String makeDivision(int introducedDividend, int introducedDivisor) {

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder reminder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor = new StringBuilder("0.");
StringBuilder lastReminderNumber = new StringBuilder();


int dividend = Math.abs(introducedDividend);
int divisor = Math.abs(introducedDivisor);
checkExceptions(divisor);

Integer divisorMuplipliedByQuotient = 0;
Integer reminderInInteger = 0;
Integer newReminder = 0;

String[] digits = String.valueOf(dividend).split("");

mainMethodForCalculateDivision(dividend, divisor, digits, reminderInInteger, reminder, divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, result, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor,
        newReminder, lastReminderNumber);
return result.toString();
```

}

И mainMethodForCalculateDivision :

```
private String mainMethodForCalculateDivision(Integer dividend, int divisor, String[] digits, Integer reminderInInteger, StringBuilder reminder, Integer divisorMuplipliedByQuotient,
                                          StringBuilder result, StringBuilder quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, StringBuilder quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor,
                                          Integer newReminder, StringBuilder lastReminderNumber) {
if (dividend == 0) {
    drawResultForDividentThatEqualsZero(result, divisor);
    return result.toString();
}
if (dividend >= divisor) {
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        calculateDivisionWhenDividentMoreOrEqualsDivisor(reminder, digits, i, divisor, divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, dividend,
                result, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor, newReminder, lastReminderNumber);
    }
    improveResultViewing(dividend, divisor, result, quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor, lastReminderNumber,
            reminderInInteger);
    return result.toString();
}
checkIfDividentEqualsZeroOrLessThanDivisorAndCalculate(dividend, divisor, reminder, reminderInInteger, digits, divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, newReminder, quotientForDividentMoreThanDivisor,
        quotientForDividentLessThanDivisor, result, lastReminderNumber);
return result.toString();
```

}

Может не получается перевести со StringBuilder в String, но если и так, то не понимаю, где именно..

Comment: в expected и SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR вертикальные палки разные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В expected и SYMBOL_VERTICAL_BAR вертикальные палки разные.